# In MPI_Gather(), MPI_Scatter() what is the difference between send count and receive count?

Tags: c++, c, memory, mpi, message-passing

In MPI gather and scatter there is two counts for send and receive. I checked the docs and found out that both should have the same value.

Ex:- In `MPI_Gather()` both `send_count` and `receive_count` should have the size of the send buffer size. https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Gather.html

Can someone explain what is the purpose of this redundant parameters?

Comment: The sizes should be equal only when the send and receive datatypes are the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To some extent, you are allowed to use different types - but the total size needs to match.

Or to be more precise, [the standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) explains:

> The type signature of `sendcount`, `sendtype` on each process must be
>   equal to the type signature of `recvcount`, `recvtype` at the root. This
>   implies that the amount of data sent must be equal to the amount of
>   data received, pairwise between each process and the root. Distinct
>   type maps between sender and receiver are still allowed.

Comment: as an illustration, you can send one vector of 1000 MPI_DOUBLE (sendcount=1, sendtype=derived datatype), and receive 1000 MPI_DOUBLE (recvcount=1000, recvtype=MPI_DOUBLE). if you are using Open MPI, keep in mind that is use case is not correctly handled by the default coll/tuned collective module

Comment: You mean, if we are using different data types on send and receive calls, they can have different counts. Okay :) Thank you!